# Time complexity analysis - how to simplify the expression

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

My algorithm's complexity has the below expression. But I am not sure how to simplify this further to express in Big-O notation.

```
   T(n) = 3 * T(n-1) + 3 * T(n-2) + 3 * T(n-3) + ... + 3 *T(1)
   T(1) takes constant time.
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculating T(n-1), we get:

```
T(n-1) = 3*T(n-2) + 3*T(n-3) + ... + 3*T(1)
```

So effectively,

```
T(n) = 3*T(n-1) + T(n-1) = 4*T(n-1) = 4*(4*T(n-2))
```

Thus **T(n) = 4<sup>(n - 1)</sup>.**